# Trying to cut and insert rows from one worksheet to another as long as there are values in any of the cells of the row

Tags: excel, vba

[Template on CBC][1]Hello looking for major help to solve the above problem/issue I have? Not sure how to tweak it or any criterion formula there is to use as i am pretty new to this! Thank you! I use the macro recorder to get the below formula but failed at tweaking it. Tried looking up videos but i failed too HAHA

Basically I have a array of data on the "data" Worksheet and would like to cut it over, and this datas differ from time to time after i import them. So I enlarge the entire range to the bottom so it covers even longer data set if needed but however, since i am inserting the data i would like to insert the rows with data and exclude the empty rows whenever i execute the macro. Mainly the idea behind this macro. Thank you!

````
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Rows("1:4").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=93
    Rows("1:105").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-138
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("CBC").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
    Rows("5:5").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("C9").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=126
    Range("C9:C146").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
End Sub```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP1Hw.jpg
````

Comment: Why are you deleting rows 1 to 4? Then you want to insert the rows 1 to 105 to row 10 of CBC sheet?

Comment: So when I import the data in, row 1 to 4 are rows that I do not need hence I omit them out, then after that with the removal of row 1 to 4, I then select the new range of 1 to 105 to cut the data over, i over specified the range to 105 since my data set can differ from time to time hence I wanted to make sure all data is included but I am not sure how I can set a criteria for this situation either. 

Or is there a better way to incorporate the code? Thank You!

Comment: Unclear what you want. Explain how you would do this manually in excel? Or screen shots of starting point / desired end point.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your goal this should work:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
        'This will get the last row with data in sheet Data on Column A
        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim RangeToCopy As Range
        'This will get the whole range to copy to the next sheet
        Set RangeToCopy = .Range("A5", .Cells(LastRow, .UsedRange.Columns.Count))
    End With
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CBC")
        'Paste the whole data from RangeToCopy to the CBC sheet
        .Range("A4").Resize(RangeToCopy.Rows.Count, RangeToCopy.Columns.Count).Insert xlDown
        .Range("A4").Resize(RangeToCopy.Rows.Count, RangeToCopy.Columns.Count).Value = RangeToCopy.Value
        RangeToCopy.Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Alright great let me try, however would like to check if i add this on to the code I have? Or I Create another macro with just this codes? Thank you! Pardon me

Comment: This is the whole macro you recorded, but written instead with the only code you would need.

Comment: Hmm that is weird, tried to create another module and assign the module to a button but doesnt seem to work, am i missing something?

Comment: Remove the macro you recorded and paste my code on that module, then look fro the "Test" procedure.

Comment: Alright it works, however there is this slight problem. Could it be slightly tweaked to cutting the data instead of copying as my objective is to clear the "data" worksheet after the data is transferred over.

As of now, the data can be transferred over however it is transferred below the template, is it possible to insert the data over to "CBC" worksheet but above my template that is on the CBC worksheet?

Comment: @HowardFoo where does your template start? which row?

Comment: Apologies, I think I didnt make myself clear just now sorry! Basically the data on "Data" Sheet is to be cut and inserted above the 'CBC' Sheet as there is a template from ROW 4 and below. So best scenario is to insert above row 4. Thank you, really feeling lost HAHA

Comment: I managed to add a shiftdown command after the insert however, now it just copies the wrong portion i think, the incomplete data set as compared to previously. Just need to fine tune the data set copied over that is all. Thank you

Comment: hmm to clarify, basically the data that are being copied over now is the first row specified which is A5 and in between is just blanks till my template beneath. 

The last row is left on the "data" sheet instead.

Comment: Yes, Finally got it!!!!! OMG thank you so much, life savior. Appreciate your help alot. Apologies as I am a total newbie in macros but I have learnt. Thank you once again!

Comment: oh just realized the last row only has data in column e, possible for me to tweak such that the code will take into account that as well?

Comment: Alright i solved it by change the value of row count 1 to 5 instead. So would like to check if by doing that, it will take into account column a to e now?